# Sharedpreferences saving arraylist<integer> with double values in release version

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, release

So I'm having an issue and I can't seem to find a cause for it so I'm here asking for some help.
I was able to find where the problem is coming from, but I can't find why it happens, here's what I have.

This is a sample of what I'm trying to save in the sharedpreferences.

```
public class Registo implements Serializable {
    int id;
    String name;
    ArrayList<Integer> commitedViolations= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I do all the process of saving it

```
public void addRegisto(Context context, Registo registo) {
        ArrayList<Registo> registos = getRegistos(context);
        if (registos == null)
            registos = new ArrayList<>();
        registos.add(registo);
        saveRegistos(context, registos);
    }



public void saveRegistos(Context context, ArrayList<Registo> favorites) {
    // used for store arrayList in json format
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

    editor.putString(REGISTOS, jsonFavorites);

    editor.apply();
}
```

And here's where magic happens, when I retrieve the objects I saved in the device, the arrayList of the object that was saved with the following values [200, 201, 202], now returns them as Double values [200.0, 201.0, 202.0].

I made a workaround, but I wanna know why this happens.

```
public ArrayList<Registo> getRegistos(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<Registo> registos;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(REGISTOS)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(REGISTOS, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Registo[] registosItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, Registo[].class);

        // <WORKAROUND>
            for (Registo registosItem : registosItems) {
                for (int i = 0; i < registosItem.getCommitedViolations().size(); i++) {
                    String str = String.valueOf(registosItem.getCommitedViolations().get(i));
                    double valueAsDouble = Double.parseDouble(str);
                    int valueAsInt= (int) valueAsDouble;
                    registosItem.getCommitedViolations().set(i, valueAsInt);
                }
            }
        // </WORKAROUND>


        registos = Arrays.asList(registosItems);
        registos = new ArrayList<>(registos);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<Registo>) registos;
}
```

**PS. And the weirdest part about this is that the debug version works perfectly, this bug only happens on the release version.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with `gson` and has nothing to do with `SharedPreferences`, since they will not modify the String you are saving.

The error lies within `gson` serializing and deserializing `Integer`. You can see one question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507997/how-to-prevent-gson-from-expressing-integers-as-floats).

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (Registo registosItem : registosItems) {
            for (int i = 0; i < registosItem.getCommitedViolations().size(); i++) {
                String str = String.valueOf(registosItem.getCommitedViolations().get(i));
                int valueAsInt= Integer.parseInt(str);
                registosItem.getCommitedViolations().set(i, valueAsInt);
            }
        }
```

This should fix your issue regarding the doubles, why don't you parse the string directly?

Comment: Could there be a reason that your int is too big?