# Deserializing arbitrary JSON in Java with Gson and respecting integers

Tags: java, json, gson

I have some JSON string snippets which could look like this:

`{label: "My Label"}`

`{maxlength: 5}`

`{contact: {name: "John", "age": 5, children: [{"name": "Mary"]}}`

etc, i.e. it could be *any* JSON object with any key names or value types.

Right now I am deserializing doing something pretty simple like this:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
Object newValue = gson.fromJson(stringValue, Object.class);
```

And this is working for 99% of the use cases. But [as is mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507997/how-to-prevent-gson-from-expressing-integers-as-floats), it is converting any integers to doubles.

I'm fine registering a type adapter as is recommended elsewhere. So I wrote the following:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new DoubleToInt())
                        .create();
Object newValue = gson.fromJson(stringValue, Object.class);

private static class DoubleToInt implements JsonDeserializer<Object>{

    @Override  
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        // do my custom stuff here

        return json;
    }
}
```

**But this isn't working at all.** It's like the type adapter is not even getting registered because breakpoints never even hit in the `deserialize` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the post you link suggested, you should create custom class, so I did and it's working correctly:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new DoubleToInt())
            .create();
        String stringValue = "{contact: {name: \"John\", \"age\": 5, children: [{\"name\": \"Mary\"}]}}";

        MyClass newValue = gson.fromJson(stringValue, MyClass.class);
        System.out.println(newValue.toString());
    }

    private static class DoubleToInt implements JsonDeserializer<MyClass> {

        @Override
        public MyClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

            // do my custom stuff here

            return new MyClass(json);
        }
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private JsonElement element;

    MyClass(JsonElement element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return element.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the post you linked, they suggested using a custom class in order to tell what data types you should use instead of using Object.class.  Have you tried doing that?

```
    class CustomClass{
      String label;
      int maxLength;
      ...
    }

    Object newValue = gson.fromJson(stringValue, CustomClass.class);
```

Comment: I have no idea what the data will be, what I gave above are just examples. It could literally be any JSON object.

Comment: gson.fromJson(stringValue, JsonObject.class); ?

Comment: @citizenconn with my solution you can have any json element

Comment: @Justin your answer is correct but I was tripped up on the field types.